# How to edit Shapefile Attributes?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, csv, excel

How might I go about exporting a polygon shapefile (e.g. CSV) so that attributes (not geometry) are editable by others, and importing it with the changed attributes (of which there are several columns worth)?

I tried the **mmqgis** plugin (Transfer > Attributes Export/Join to/from CSV file), but
1) it seems to only be able to import one attribute at a time and
2) creates a separate temp.shp without geometry and
3) does not attach the new attributes to the existing polygon shapefile.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here, or do you have a better solution for my task at hand?

[image: attributes polygon qgis]

Thanks!

Comment: You need a unique id to match your csv to the polygon attributes (they need to match correctly)

Comment: "shapeid" does match in nodes.shp and attributes.csv.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the attributes of a shapefile are stored in an extra dbase-file.  for example: mypolygons.shp contains geometries, mypolygons.dbf contains attributes. via an id the attributes are connected to the polygons. so just simple load your dbf file into capable software (e.g libreoffice) , edit attributes  and your done

Comment: Excellent, I opened and edited it successfully in MS Access. Thanks!

Comment: But be sure not to change the order of rows. Don't sort data and don't add/delete rows.  You may find that Access interferes with the formatting of data, you may have more repeatable results with libreoffice.

Answer (score 6):

I do this using `R`. There is a package called `foreign` which enables reading and writing of `dbf` files.

```
library(foreign) # load the package

data <- read.dbf('myfile.dbf') # read the dbf as a dataframe
```

In this case I just wanted to change the rounding of a column `pop_den`:

```
data$pop_den <- round(data$pop_den) # trim data (removing significant figures)

write.dbf(data, 'myfile.dbf')      # write data. This OVERWRITES your existing dbf
```

The caveats about re-ordering and adding/deleting rows also apply. It's hard to do these by accident in `R`, but you should still be careful.