# Changing Number values to specific text in Attribute table (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, sql, attribute-table, editing

I'm working with a column in an attribute table that has number values and *NULL* values. I want to create a new column in which *NULL* values are changed to "Directory" and any number values to "Submitted."

I used the formula from the answer from [How to do a simple find and replace in QGIS field calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42862/how-to-do-a-simple-find-and-replace-in-qgis-field-calculator) and successfully converted *NULL* to text.

[image]

How can I use a version of this formula to also convert all number values to the word "Submitted"?

Answer (score 4):

Add a `"New_Field"` of type `Text`. Select the values that are not `NULL` using "Select features using an expression" from the attribute table, and enter the following formula:

```
"Field_Name" is not null
```

Where: `"Field_Name"` is the field that contains numbers (is not `NULL`). Then update the `"New_Field"` and write `'Submitted'` in the expression, and use `Update Selected`, as shown below:

[image]

Then use `Invert Selection` [image] and write 'Directory' and click `Update Selected`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify if content is number, then try the below regexp:

```
CASE WHEN regexp_match(( "Field_Name" ) , '[0-9]') THEN 'submitted'  END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression to return `'Directory'` for values of `NULL` and 'Submitted' for values containing a digit in the attribute  named `fieldname`:

```
case 
when fieldname is NULL then 'Directory'
when fieldname ~ '[0-9]' then 'Submitted'
end
```

Like this, if field is not NULL and does not contain any digit, the output will be empty. You might define an `else` condition to set an output for such cases.