# How to bulk delete shapefile columns?

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, ogr, attribute-table

I have shapefile with next attribute table :

[image: attribute table]

(name of features, unique number for each feature of layer)

I must split shapefile by `NAME` field, but in result in attribute tables of layers should be only unique number column (see picture):

[image]

Split layer by Name I create in QGIS. Is there any solution to delete column "Name" in many shapefiles (about 800)?

I use ArcGIS, QGIS, PostGIS, OGR...

Comment: maybe this is helpful? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35093/how-to-edit-shapefile-attributes/35102#35102

Comment: You need to write small script in (Python for Q-GIS or ArcGIS) OR if you are using ArcGIS then in Arctool box right click on field and click on batch processing and insert all file names and delete the column..thanks

Comment: @Sunil,  thanks! In ArcGIS Data Management Tools - Fields - Delete Field run Butch processing. It is help me. Please write answer for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write small script in (Python for Q-GIS or ArcGIS) OR if you are using ArcGIS then in Arctoolbox- Data Management Tools - Fields - Delete Field run Batch processing..

I hope it will help you : )  all the best thanks..